# Is there any way to spread an announcement?

Tags: discussion

In the question: [Compendium of the Best Approximation and Hardness Results for NP optimization problems](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/compendium-of-the-best-approximation-and-hardness-results-for-np-optimization-pro),
it is pointed out that a wiki for computational problems similar to [Complexity Zoo](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo) can be beneficial for the researchers. It is a great help for researchers to know the best algorithmic results (lower and/or bound) related to a problem. Apparently, the zoo people started a new wiki for computational problems: [complexity garden](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Garden). I contacted the editors of complexity garden and they agreed to devote this wiki to algorithmic results of problems in addition to its original complexity related scope.

Now, I would like to announce this opportunity to populate the Garden. I can add an answer to the above question, but I think not many people will see that. **Is there anyway to announce this using cstheory.stackexchange?**

Comment: In any case, adding an answer to the above question would be a good starting point. The question will appear on the front page if there is a recent answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if the Q&A format works for this, but maybe the blog is a good place to solicit requests for contributions ? If you contact the cstheory blog editors (Aaron Sterling and Joe Fitzsimmons - look at their profile page), maybe they can insert an announcement in the next post.

Comment: I'm not against this in principle, but the garden has been around for years. What exactly would we be announcing that is new?

Comment: @Joe It was around, but it was devoted to computational problems and their related complexity classes, not related algorithmic results. I was planning to a start a new wiki for the algorithmic results, but I thought when there is one wiki for computational problems, we can have all the information in one place. So, I contacted the Zoo people and changed the scope of the Garden to include algorithmic results. This part is what makes Garden different from what it was.

Comment: @Babak: Does the garden now include new material, in line with the new scope?

Comment: @Aaron I changed the description and added an algorithm  subsection (although, empty for most problems now) for the existing problems. I added the Set Cover problem as an example for the algorithmic results and going to add problems related to my research in course of time.

Comment: @Babak: I think you might have significant trouble in getting people to participate if you have only added a small amount of material. I would suggest that you try to get a smaller group of people to populate more entries before you ask people to make a public announcement. Otherwise, you will find that people show up once, realise there is no content, and leave without ever contributing. As such, I'm not really comfortable adding an announcement of this on its own, as it doesn't really strike me as important news just yet.

Comment: However there is another thread, where we are wondering about what static pages to add to the blog. A resources page might be a good idea, in which case we would list the zoo and garden along with the updated mandate.

Comment: @Joe The problem is that I don't have a good way to find the smaller group of people. The only thing that comes to my mind is to answer the cstheory question I asked before and hope to find 3 or 4 more persons. I am not sure this is enough.

Comment: @Joe: I agree, and was thinking something similar.

Comment: I added an answer to cstheory question to see what kind of feedback I get: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/compendium-of-the-best-approximation-and-hardness-results-for-np-optimization-pro/7974#7974

Comment: @Babak: That's not something we can really help you with. I'd maybe first suggest other students you may know in your department or else where, or simply adding content yourself until you have a critical mass.